# How to get rows in reversed order in HBase REST curl

Tags: rest, hadoop, hbase, stargate, nosql

I can get all rows from a table with

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8080/table/*
```

I can limit the rows number with

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8080/table/*?limit=10
```

The problem is the rows are always the first 10 inserted and not the last 10.

I wonder to get reversed order, specially combined with the limit parameter.

I know about the setReversed parameter and in HBase shell this works fine:

```
scan 'table', {LIMIT => 10, REVERSED=> TRUE}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it wasn't implemented in older versions but patch is available.

Here is the related [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-16299)

Eventually it should be

`curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8080/table/*?limit=10&reversed=true`